# Action bar разные ориентации

Tags: actionbar, tabs, android

Доброго времени суток, есть action bar  тип навигации NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS и в меню кнопка поиск, но в портретной ориентации не видно текста рядом с иконкой хотя стоит withText,
[image]
 а в ландшафтной кнопки и табы в одну линию, но у кнопки есть подпись
[image]

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search_hotel"
      android:title="@string/action_search_for_hotel"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      sabd:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom|collapseActionView|"
      sabd:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

хотелось бы чтоб у кнопок всегда был виден текст и табы в моих ориентациях были внизу.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Команда гугл не рекомендует использовать DrawerNavigation + ActionBar(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)

Comment: спасибо не знал

Comment: "Команда гугл не рекомендует использовать DrawerNavigation + ActionBar(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)" ибо избыточно. Либо то либо то - вполне логично.

Comment: кстати не смотря на рекомендации  play marcet содержит и табы и боковое меню

Answer (score 1):

Советую Вам использовать `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

Здесь есть пример https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout